# The use of ? operator in F# deedle

Tags: f#, deedle

I understand `?` is used to access data, such as `column` in `Frame`, but the returned `column` will be in `float`.
How about assignment of new column in a `Frame`?

```
 let second = Series.ofValues(["d";"e";"f"])
 let df?second = second
```

I tested this new column will stay as `string`, actually, I just would like to know if there is a place that systematically explain the use of `?` operator.

Comment: This question may be simple. but such question is answered in python/pandas community. Whoever downvote this is discourage ppl adopting F#/Deedle

Answer (score 2):

Think maybe that https://github.com/BlueMountainCapital/Deedle/blob/master/docs/content/frame.fsx from line 231 and downwards gives some explanations on how to use it.

It does not explain other hows or whys, but might be what you need or want...